# Is my usage of LINQ to XML correct when I'm trying to find multiple values in the same XML file?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, linq

I have to extract values belonging to certain elements in an XML file and this is what I ended up with.

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("request.xml");
var year = (string)doc.Descendants("year").FirstOrDefault();
var id = (string)doc.Descendants("id").FirstOrDefault();
```

I'm guessing that for each statement I'm iterating through the entire file looking for the first occurrence of the element called year/id. Is this the correct way to do this? It seems like there has to be a way where one would avoid unnecessary iterations. I know what I'm looking for and I know that the elements are going to be there even if the values may be null.

I'm thinking in the lines of a select statement with both "year" and "id" as conditions.

For clearance, I'm looking for certain elements and their respective values. There'll most likely be multiple occurrences of the same element but FirstOrDefault() is fine for that.

Further clarification:
As requested by the legend Jon Skeet, I'll try to clarify further. The XML document contains fields such as `<year>2015</year>` and `<id>123032</id>` and I need the values. I know which elements I'm looking for, and that they're going to be there. In the sample XML below, I would like to get 2015, The Emperor, something and 30.

Sample XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<documents xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

<make>Apple</make>
<year>2015</year>
<customer>
  <name>The Emperor</name>
  <level2>
    <information>something</information>
  </level2>
  <age>30</age>
</customer>
```

Comment: You should really clarify *exactly* what you're trying to find - in particular, currently your `id` and `year` elements could be entirely separate, with no common ancestors beyond the document root. If you want those to be separate queries, and if you don't care whether about anything other than the first element, then that's fine... but it may not be what you're trying to do.

Comment: Show us what the xml look like (just a short template), and what you are trying to achieve (I need to request the nodes by year and id for example)

Answer (score 1):

A code that doesn't parse the whole xml twice would be like:

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("request.xml");

string year = null;
string id = null;
bool yearFound = false, idFound = false;

foreach (XElement ele in doc.Descendants())
{
    if (!yearFound && ele.Name == "year")
    {
        year = (string)ele;
        yearFound = true;
    }
    else if (!idFound && ele.Name == "id")
    {
        id = (string)ele;
        idFound = true;
    }

    if (yearFound && idFound)
    {
        break;
    }
}
```

As you can see you are trading lines of code for speed :-) I do feel the code is still quite readable.

if you really need to optimize up to the last line of code, you could put the names of the elements in two variables (because otherwise there will be many temporary `XName` creation)

```
// before the foreach
XName yearName = "year";
XName idName = "id";
```

and then

```
if (!yearFound && ele.Name == yearName)
...
if (!idFound && ele.Name == idName)
```